# Installing Caffe dependencies locally

Tags: build, dependencies, installation, redhat, caffe

I'm trying to build Caffe on a Red-Hat machine on which I'm logged in remotely and don't have root access. Is there any way to build its dependencies locally without asking the super-user to get them installed?

The Caffe dependencies and installation instructions for RHEL are listed [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_yum.html).

Comment: [Caffe installation on CentOS without root access](http://autchen.github.io/guides/2015/04/03/caffe-install.html)

Comment: Docker?  I have found Docker containers really useful for Caffe on Ubuntu.